# Git keeps committing untracked files

Tags: git, github

I have been using Git for a while.

I have some changes on my local branch:

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    modified: xyzzy

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    abc
```

I want to commit only xyzzy changes, and not abc. Since abc is untracked, I go ahead and do `git commit -m "my change"`.

And the untracked changes abc are committed as well! I can see:

```
create mode 100624 abc
create mode 100624 xyzzy
```

What is going on here? How can I resolve this?

**Solutions tried:**

1. Using `git clean -f abc` - it still appears when committed anyway
2. Checking for unintentional git aliases `git config -e` - as expected, I did not set up any config

Comment: If you commit with nothing in the index, you should normally get an error.

Comment: What do you mean with nothing in the index? I have staged xyzzy

Comment: Sorry I misread. `git commit` makes a commit from the index. If the file is untracked, it will only get commited if you specify `-a` or so.

Comment: Maybe you accidentally aliased `commit` as `commit -a`?

Comment: Nope, I checked with `git config -e`, there's no section on `[alias]` at all

Comment: What does git status say AFTER git commit? Do you still have that list of untracked files? git commit -m should not add untracked files. As already mentioned before, an alias maybe? Type alias to list your aliases.

Comment: Yes, `abc` still shows up in untracked files. But at the same time, it is also shown as part of the commit.....

Comment: The strangest thing is that if I am to do `git rm abc`, then I get `fatal: pathspec 'abc' does not match any files`. If I try to do `git add abc`, then some other random file altogether is added to the staging area!

Comment: The definition of an *untracked file* is a file that isn't in Git's index. Git builds new commits from the files that *are* in Git's index. So it's literally impossible to put an untracked file into a new commit. It's not clear what is actually going on here (perhaps you have a rogue pre-commit hook, or are working in a folder where something is actively subverting your work, e.g., Dropbox is changing files on you) but for the file to go into the commit, it has to go into Git's index, which causes it to be a tracked file.

Comment: That makes sense. At the end of the day, what should the workaround be? I just deleted the repository, get a new local copy of the repository, and create an entirely new branch and that branch does not have this issue. But I'm not sure if there's any better way

Answer (score -2):

To specifically add a single file, stage only that file

`git stage xyzzy`

Now executing the commit command will only consider the file xyzzy

`git commit -m "my change"`

Comment: Yes, that is what i did. I used git add (same as git stage). So you can see in the post description that xyzzy is considered as a change to be committed while abc is not

Comment: I think git commit will commit all the files from Stage- not just one file 'xyzzy' which is in your example. and what is git stage? it is 'git add filename' to add a file to stage/index.